# Missing arrow tips and colors

Tags: plotting, graphics3d, color

**My main problem is:** I plotted a curve here, but the tip of some arrows are missing. Why does this happen, and how can I fix this?

*Not the main problem:* Also, I once tried to make the arrows with different colors, but all of them would be of the same color as the first one. How can I make them different colors? And I have a strong impression that I'm not being intelligent using `Graphics3D` all this much, for every single arrow. It must have a cleaner way to do it. (Maybe I should ask a different question for this, but I don't want to flood the site. If you can help me with the main problem, I'll be happy already)

[**EDIT:**  wxffles already helped me with this issue in the comments. What is left is the main problem now.]

[image]

The code as it is now, in case it helps:

```
a[t_] := {1 + Cos[t], Sin[t], 2 Sin[t/2]}
tf[t_] := {(-Sin[t])/(Sqrt[1 + Cos[t/2]^2]), (Cos[t])/(Sqrt[
     1 + Cos[t/2]^2]), (Cos[t/2])/(Sqrt[1 + Cos[t/2]^2])}
bf[t_] := 
 Rationalize@{(-0.5 Cos[t] Sin[t/2] + Cos[t/2] Sin[t])/ 
    Sqrt[1.625 + 0.375 Cos[t]], (-Cos[t/2] Cos[t] - 
      0.5 Sin[t/2] Sin[t])/Sqrt[1.625 + 0.375 Cos[t]], 
   1/Sqrt[1.625 + 0.375 Cos[t]]}
nf[t_] := {-((3 + 12 Cos[t] + Cos[2 t])/(
   2 Sqrt[3 + Cos[t]] Sqrt[13 + 3 Cos[t]])), -(((6 + Cos[t]) Sin[t])/(
   Sqrt[3 + Cos[t]] Sqrt[13 + 3 Cos[t]])), -((2 Sin[t/2])/(
   Sqrt[3 + Cos[t]] Sqrt[13 + 3 Cos[t]]))}    


Show[ParametricPlot3D[{1 + Cos[t], Sin[t], 2 Sin[t/2]}, {t, 0, 
       4 \[Pi]}, 
      PlotStyle -> Directive[RGBColor[0.91`, 0.`, 0.`], Opacity[1.`]], 
      BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, Boxed -> False, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0}], 
     Graphics3D[Arrowheads[0.02], Arrow[{a[0], a[0] + tf[0]}]], 
     Graphics3D[Arrow[{a[0], a[0] + tf[0]}]], 
     Graphics3D[Arrow[{a[1], a[1] + tf[1]}]], 
     Graphics3D[Arrow[{a[Pi/2], a[Pi/2] + tf[Pi/2]}]], 
     Graphics3D[Arrow[{a[2], a[2] + tf[2]}]], 
     Graphics3D[Arrow[{a[Pi], a[Pi] + tf[Pi]}]], 
     Graphics3D[Arrow[{a[3 Pi/2], a[3 Pi/2] + tf[3 Pi/2]}]], 
     Graphics3D[Arrow[{a[2 Pi], a[2 Pi] + tf[2 Pi]}]], 
     Graphics3D[Arrow[{a[0], a[0] + bf[0]}]], 
     Graphics3D[Arrow[{a[0], a[0] + bf[0]}]], 
     Graphics3D[Arrow[{a[1], a[1] + bf[1]}]], 
     Graphics3D[Arrow[{a[Pi/2], a[Pi/2] + bf[Pi/2]}]], 
     Graphics3D[Arrow[{a[2], a[2] + bf[2]}]], 
     Graphics3D[Arrow[{a[Pi], a[Pi] + bf[Pi]}]], 
     Graphics3D[Arrow[{a[3 Pi/2], a[3 Pi/2] + bf[3 Pi/2]}]], 
     Graphics3D[Arrow[{a[2 Pi], a[2 Pi] + bf[2 Pi]}]], 
     Graphics3D[Arrow[{a[0], a[0] + nf[0]}]], 
     Graphics3D[Arrow[{a[0], a[0] + nf[0]}]], 
     Graphics3D[Arrow[{a[1], a[1] + nf[1]}]], 
     Graphics3D[Arrow[{a[Pi/2], a[Pi/2] + nf[Pi/2]}]], 
     Graphics3D[Arrow[{a[2], a[2] + nf[2]}]], 
     Graphics3D[Arrow[{a[Pi], a[Pi] + nf[Pi]}]], 
     Graphics3D[Arrow[{a[3 Pi/2], a[3 Pi/2] + nf[3 Pi/2]}]], 
     Graphics3D[Arrow[{a[2 Pi], a[2 Pi] + nf[2 Pi]}]]]
```

Thanks for your time.

Comment: `PlotRange -> All`?

Comment: `Graphics3D` can take a list of primitives, so you don't need a separate `Graphics3D` for each arrow.  You can also have nested lists to provide scoping for your styling.  E.g. `Graphics3D[{{Red, Arrow[...]}, Arrow[...], ...}]`

Comment: Hey, thanks! Your comment really helped me (:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me shorten your example a little bit

```
par =
  ParametricPlot3D[{1 + Cos[t], Sin[t], 2 Sin[t/2]}, {t, 0, 4 \[Pi]},
   PlotStyle -> Red,
   Boxed -> False,
   AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0},
   AspectRatio -> 1];

arr =
  Graphics3D[
   {
    Arrowheads[0.02],
    {Red, Arrow[{a[0], a[0] + tf[0]}]},
    {Green, Arrow[{a[1], a[1] + tf[1]}]},
    {Blue, Arrow[{a[Pi/2], a[Pi/2] + tf[Pi/2]}]},
    {Black, Arrow[{a[2 Pi], a[2 Pi] + nf[3 Pi]}]}
    }];

Show[par, arr, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Comment: Great. I didn't knew that you could name the graph and do something like `Show[par, arr, PlotRange -> All]`, also. Very helpful and instructive. (:

Comment: @IvoTerek Thanks :)